# Web scraping Amazon and create a list of dic

Tags: python, list, selenium, dictionary, web-scraping

I am experiencing some troubles with my code when scraping the Amazon site with selenium.
I want a list of dictionaries of title and author of the books as keys and values, in the format:

```
[{TITLE:'x', AUTHOR:'y'}
{TITLE:'z', AUTHOR:'w'}]
```

However it returns me a dictionary of lists, with keys and values repeated, in the format:

```
{TITLE:['x'], AUTHOR:['y']}
{TITLE:['x', 'z'], AUTHOR:['y', 'r']}
{TITLE:['x', 'z', 'q'], AUTHOR:['y', 'r', 'p']}
```

That is: it iterates and repeat the values for each key. It shows me the previous value, and includes it in the next dictionary. It is not supposed to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

Firstly, I import the libraries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
```

Secondly, I install the proper version o chromedrive:

```
Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Thirdly, I open the browser automaticaly:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('window-size=250,1000')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dambr\Documents\scrapping\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Fourtly, I open the Amazon site:

```
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com.br/')
a = driver.find_element(By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox")
a.click()
a.send_keys('python')
b = driver.find_element(By.ID, "nav-search-submit-button")
b.click()
sleep(3)
```

Finally, I take all the titles and authors of my search and try to store in a list of dictionaries:

```
dic_livros = {'TÍTULO':[], 'AUTOR':[]}
lista = '//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]'
for i in lista:
    title = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal']")
    author = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-size-base']")    
    for (each_title, each_author) in zip(title, author):
        dic_livros['TÍTULO'].append(each_title.text)
        dic_livros['AUTOR'].append(each_author.text)
        print(dic_livros)
```

Where, precisely is my mistake?

Here is what my output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your last step needs two changes:
replace first line with

```
dic_livros = []
```

then for the for loop:

```
for (each_title, each_author) in zip(title, author):
    dic_livros.append({'Titulo':each_title.text,'Autor':each_author.text})
```

Comment: Thanks, Jacob. It resolved my problem of create a list o dic, however it didn't resolve my problem of repeating the previous title and author in the next list of dic.

Comment: can you print what title and author look like?

Comment: Hi Jacob, I've just insert a printscreen of my input

Comment: if you want a list of dictionaries just pull the print back two tabs, it'll run through and then just print the final output once. You are printing every time one author and book is added which I think may be the issue. It sounds trivial but push the print back two tabs and see if that gives you the solution you want.